# Rakefile - access variable defined in a prerequisite

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

Is there some way to access a variable defined in a prerequisite? e.g.

```
task :new_file do
    filename = 'foobar.txt' # in reality I ask the user for the filename
    File.write(filename, 'Some glorious content')
end

task :new_file! => [:new_file] do
    exec "vim #{filename.inspect}"
end
```

I'd like `rake new_file!` to simply be a shorthand for `rake new_file` along with launching vim for whatever file I created in the `new_file` task.

All I can think of is populating a global variable `FILENAME` in `:new_file` and using it in `new_file!` and then clearing it, but if there is a "more Rake" way to do it, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define the variable outside the tasks like this:

```
filename = 'default.name'

task :new_file do
    filename = 'foobar.txt' # in reality I ask the user for the filename
    File.write(filename, 'Some glorious content')
end

task :new_file! => [:new_file] do
    # filename will be visible here too, and its value was set in new_file
    exec "vim #{filename.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: This is really the same as me defining a global variable, which is something I'd rather avoid.